# Is there a way to get a button from its location?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a game where rectangular buttons are arranged to make squares. I need to detect if 4 activated buttons make a square. I tried out some stuff with lists, and I need to see if there are any buttons around the button pressed and if they are activated.

So I need to find the buttons based on estimate location(position). I know I can find the location of an object but not an object from it's location.

Here is some code I saw from another similar post, but that didn't work out:

```
            Button btn = (Button)sender;

            Point btnPos = btn.Location;
            int wantX = btnPos.X + 100;
            int wantY = btnPos.Y + 110;

            var maxDifference = 10;
            var predictedLocation = new Point(wantX, btnPos.Y);
            var theButtonAtYourLocation = components.Components
                .Cast<Component>()
                .OfType<Button>()
                .FirstOrDefault(button => Math.Abs(button.Location.X - predictedLocation.X) <= maxDifference &&
                                          Math.Abs(button.Location.Y - predictedLocation.Y) <= maxDifference);

            label1.Text += theButtonAtYourLocation?.Name;
```

It give me an error: *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

So what I'm trying to achieve is a virtual "radius" around the button, and any buttons in that radius. Is this too far fetched or is it possible?

Comment: A button control has a Location property (which you got already), as well as `Size`. As for the error you're getting, which line and value is null?

Comment: What is _components_?

Comment: You could perhaps try getting a collection of your buttons and then iterate through them checking the location of each. Use something like `foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())`

Comment: That sounds like a plan

Comment: That is the answer for my question which sets things into perspective!